# How to display currently playing iPhone song on Mac

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, music

I sit there with MacBook on my lap and iPhone in my pocket listening to music from the iPhone with headphones.

Is there a way to display the currently playing iPhone song on the MacBook?

Comment: I doubt that is possible. I know Apple Remote works the other way around (Tells you what is playing on the Mac on the iPhone)

Comment: Not natively, but with a wifi connection and a Mac application called AirServer: 1. Connect your iPhone and your mac to the same wifi network. 2.  Start AirServer on your Mac. 3. Play music on your iPhone and select AirPlay > your MacBook. 4. Plug in your headphone into your mac. 5. See the playing song in the menu bar (AirServer icon).

Comment: @oa thanks for your suggestion but that sounds overly complicated for a feature that's also available natively. If the iPhone and the Mac are in the same network the iPhone shows up in iTunes you can play songs right there. However, im my scenario the headphones aren't plugged into the Mac but into the iPhone. So, the music is effectively playing there and not on the Mac.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to play the music directly from the Mac?